# groovy only grabbing first element of loop

Tags: groovy

I've got a very straightforward code snippet. That for some reason is 
only grabbing the first element of the loop when I try to output it in
my jsp. JcrUtils.getChildNodes returns a NodeIterator that I thought would loop through
each property. Here is the code:

```
def headerNode = JcrUtils.getChildNodes(LINKS).find{ 
    it.hasProperty("headerTitle")
    it.hasProperty("headerMeta")
}
selectHeaderTitle = headerNode.getProperty("headerTitle").getString()
selectHeaderMeta = headerNode.getProperty("headerMeta").getString()
```

JSP:

```
${header.selectHeaderTitle}
${header.selectHeaderMeta}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a list of Properties?  You'd need `findAll`, also you need to `&&` your `hasProperty` calls:

```
def headerNode = JcrUtils.getChildNodes(LINKS).findAll { 
    it.hasProperty("headerTitle") && it.hasProperty("headerMeta")
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now I'm getting the last instance of the property. Am I doing something wrong in the JSP? I thought the above would just return a list of all the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Groovy find only returns the first match.

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Iterator+Tricks